# VSTO Excel: How to check whether a range can be selected?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, range

Is there any way to check whether a Range can be selected (or used in any way), like some sort of validation?

I'm having this problem with VSTO 2.5 SE and Excel 2003. Whenever I delete these rows, **firstSelectedItem.Select()** throws an HResult error. Ok, I have already figured out a way to go round this, but I'm looking for a "better" way, some easy comparison or so to see whether **firstSelectedItem** actually can be selected, or whether I should try to select some other range.

Here's the example code.

```
    using ExcelIntOp = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

    ExcelIntOp.Range firstSelectedItem = null;

    for (int i = selectedRange.Rows.Count; i > 0; i--)
    {
      firstSelectedItem = ((ExcelIntOp.Range)selectedRange.Cells[1, 1]);

      if (firstSelectedItem.Value2 == null)
          firstSelectedItem.EntireRow.Delete(System.Type.Missing);
    }

    if (firstSelectedItem != null)
      firstSelectedItem.Select();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't `Select` `firstSelectedItem` after you have deleted it. If you don't want to check that `firstSelectedItem` is valid before selecting, then repoint it to a valid cell after the delete.

```
for (int i = selectedRange.Rows.Count; i > 0; i--)
{
  firstSelectedItem = ((ExcelIntOp.Range)selectedRange.Cells[i, 1]);

  if (firstSelectedItem.Value2 == null)
  {
      firstSelectedItem.EntireRow.Delete(System.Type.Missing);
      firstSelectedItem = ((ExcelIntOp.Range)selectedRange.Cells[i, 1]);
  }
}

firstSelectedItem.Select();
```

By the way, I'm assuming you misstyped your `firstSelectedItem` assignment statement and it should be `[i,1]` not `[1,1]`.