# Excel VSTO range delete loop stops working randomly

Tags: c#, vsto

I have a large VSTO application that takes a named range and adds rows to it throughout. A worksheet then has a button that should erase all the lines in the named range (but still leave the range intact). However, when I run that loop, it will randomly stop working. No error message, no warnings, just stops running. Some rows are deleted but not all of them and the number of rows that get deleted seems to be random. My code is pretty straightforward, the only special thing is that I want the first two lines to never erase. Heres my code

```
Excel.Workbook wb = (Excel.Workbook)Globals.ThisWorkbook.InnerObject;
            Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets["MySheet"];
            Excel.Range rng = ws.get_Range("MyRange");

            int totalRun = 0;

            foreach (Excel.Range row in rng.Areas[1].Rows)
                {
                if(totalRun>1)
                    row.EntireRow.Delete(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp);

                totalRun++;
                }
```

As you can see, I thought the problem was related to areas or something else that was only giving me a partial set but that doesnt seem to be the case. The rows I'm deleting are a mix of text and numbers. Again, some rows delete but others dont and its seemingly random. The range grows to be about 500 rows and this loop will delete as few as 10% of the lines and as as high as 75% of the lines

Also, I've already changed one of my application attributes because of proxy error messages. I thought that would also help this but it doesn't - that looks like

```
[assembly: ExcelLocale1033(false)]
```

HELP!

Comment: Is `MyRange` contiguous (i.e. `$A$1:$F$9999`, or is it a union of multiple sub-ranges (i.e. `'Sheet1'!$A$10:$S$10,'Sheet1'!$A$9:$S$9,'Sheet1'!$A$8:$S$8`)? If it's not contiguous, I would suspect it would be related to using Areas also.  If it's contiguous, you could just use something like `if (rng.Rows.Count > 2) { rng.Offset(2).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 2).EntireRow.Delete(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp); }` (syntax may be off a bit; translated ad-hoc from VBA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still dont know exactly why the code above does not work but I used the code in this answer and its working. Odd.

[VSTO Excel: How to check whether a range can be selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076372/vsto-excel-how-to-check-whether-a-range-can-be-selected)

```
for (int i = selectedRange.Rows.Count; i > 0; i--)
{
  firstSelectedItem = ((ExcelIntOp.Range)selectedRange.Cells[i, 1]);

  if (firstSelectedItem.Value2 != null)
  {
      firstSelectedItem.EntireRow.Delete(System.Type.Missing);
      firstSelectedItem = ((ExcelIntOp.Range)selectedRange.Cells[i, 1]);
  }
}
```

Comment: You were using a foreach enumerator on a collection that was being modified inside the foreach. In pure .net that would thrown an error. Appearantly not so on this com collection but underlying problem is still there